# How to correct for gain and offset errors in a signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, processing-gain

I have a signal recorded from two different detectors, with different levels of gain.

$$
S_{1}(\omega) = \alpha_{1}S(\omega) + \beta_{1} \\
S_{2}(\omega) = \alpha_{2}S(\omega) + \beta_{2}
$$

How would you correct for the gain, considering the offset in the signal is minimial.

Comment: Are you sure that is a constant offset in frequency? That would correspond to $s_1(t) = \alpha_1 \cdot s(t) + \beta_1 \cdot \delta(t)$ in the time domain.

Comment: Now, that I think about it, I guess it would rather be $S_{1}(t) = S(t)\otimes \alpha_{1}(t)$, where $\alpha_{1}$ basically is the instrument response function.

Comment: Are your gains, or instrument response functions, known?  This is easy and obvious if they are, perhaps impossible without some side experiments or calibration if not.